# Affinity Designer: Using the flood fill tool on selected area

Tags: selections, fill, affinity-designer

I want to colour an element of my drawing. To save time, I selected the area I wanted to fill and expanded the selection before using the flood fill tool. However, the pixelated white line still shows up. In other words, the expansion of my selection was completely ignored.

I wouldn't like to manually fill in the colour with the brush tool.

How could I achieve a clean fill (without the pixelated line)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the options bar you should see the tolerance and continuity settings for the flood fill tool.

[image]

Set the tolerance to 100%. It stops the tool worrying if something is painted over. If your selection has several separate areas uncheck also "contiguous".

There's also a possibility to select different blending mode than "normal" and use another layer as the fill area decision source. In my screenshot the current layer would be used if the tolerance was less than 100%. Now the tolerance is 100% and the whole selected area would be filled.